# NodeJS: unwatching a file and specifying a listener

Tags: node.js

I am using `fs.watchfile();` in NodeJS somewhat like the documentation example:

```
fs.watchFile('message.text', function (curr, prev) {});
```

When I use a listener:

```
fs.watchFile('message.text', function (curr, prev) {}, listener);
```

And unwatch the file:

```
fs.unwatchFile(message.text, listener);
```

The `unwatchfile` removes all listeners to the file instead of the specified listener. The documentation states that it should only remove the specified listener, so what is being done incorrectly?

Comment: What version of node are you using and what OS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second parameter in fs.watchFile will be an JavaScript object with options but you passed two functions.

Test case:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var listener1 = function (curr, prev) { console.log('touched 1'); };
var listener2 = function (curr, prev) { console.log('touched 2'); };

fs.watchFile('message.text', listener1);
fs.watchFile('message.text', listener2);

fs.unwatchFile('message.text', listener1);
```