# How to close fs.watch listener for a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I have an application that allows a user to continuously upload the contents of a local folder to a folder in the cloud. The application is built with `electron` and `node.js`

So the code that I need help with is this:

```
  fs.watch(getHomeDirectory(), (eventname, filename) => {
   upload(
    filename,
    `${getHomeDirectory()}/${filename}`
  );
})
```

This function is called as apart of a event listener on a button.

There is a getter, `getHomeDirectory`, function that gets the user's directory for the folder and then the `upload` function that uploads files that are added or changed in that folder.

I want it so that the application just keeps uploading files whenever a file is added or changed into the target directory.

Right now it works, but I want the user to be able to shut off the `fs.watch` so they stop listening to the folder.

I had found this stack overflow question: [NodeJS: unwatching a file and specifying a listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550222/nodejs-unwatching-a-file-and-specifying-a-listener). However this only deals with `fs.watchFile` and when I tried doing the same for `fs.watch` it did not work.

I don't know what I need to do.

Comment: Have you looked at [**https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_event_close**](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_event_close)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`fs.watch(...)` returns an instance of [fs.FSWatcher](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher), which has a `.close()` method.  So, if you want to unwatch you can:

```
const watcher = fs.watch(getHomeDirectory(), (eventname, filename) => {
  // your code here
})
```

Then, when you're done with the watcher, you would call:

```
watcher.close()
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is the correct answer because `watcher=...` is asynchronous and  `watcher.close()` will close immediately

Comment: I've updated the answer to be more clear on the fact that `watcher.close()` shouldn't be called immediately afterward.